# Windows Source-Initiated event subscription does not forward events to the Collector

Tags: windows, events, subscription

Windows Source-Initiated event subscription does not forward events to the Collector.

Below are the settings I used and the steps I took to troubleshoot the issue.

---

Source Computer Settings (OS: Windows Server 2012 R2):

1. Configured Windows Remote Management
   `winrm qc –q`
2. Configured the Event Collector service
   `wecutil qc /q`
3. Added the collector’s address to the registry or through the Group Policy Editor
   `Server=http://<Collector’s FQDN>:5985/wsman/SubscriptionManager/WEC`
4. Apply Group Policy Settings
   `gpupdate /force`

---

Collector Computer Settings (OS: Windows 7):

1. Configured Windows Remote Management
   `winrm qc –q`
2. Configured the Event Collector service
   `wecutil qc /q`
3. Enable the HTTP Compatibility Listener
   `winrm set winrm/config/Service @{EnableCompatibilityHttpListener="true"}`
4. Apply Group Policy Settings
   `gpupdate /force`
5. Create the subscription
   `wecutil cs Subscription.xml`

> ```
> <Subscription xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/03/windows/events/subscription">
>   <SubscriptionId>NotificationSubscription</SubscriptionId>
>   <SubscriptionType>SourceInitiated</SubscriptionType>
>   <Description>Alert subscription</Description>
>   <Enabled>true</Enabled>
>   <Uri>http://schemas.microsoft.com/wbem/wsman/1/windows/EventLog</Uri>
>
>   <!-- Use Normal (default), Custom, MinLatency, MinBandwidth -->
>   <ConfigurationMode>Custom</ConfigurationMode>
>
>   <Delivery Mode="Push">
>     <Batching>
>       <MaxItems>1</MaxItems>
>       <MaxLatencyTime>1000</MaxLatencyTime>
>     </Batching>
>     <PushSettings>
>       <Heartbeat Interval="60000"/>
>     </PushSettings>
>   </Delivery>
>
>   <Query>
>     <![CDATA[
>             <QueryList>
>                 <Query Path="Notification">
>                     <Select Path="Notification">*</Select>
>                 </Query>
>             </QueryList>
>         ]]>
>   </Query>
>
>   <ReadExistingEvents>true</ReadExistingEvents>
>   <TransportName>http</TransportName>
>   <ContentFormat>RenderedText</ContentFormat>
>   <Locale Language="en-US"/>
>   <LogFile>ForwardedEvents</LogFile>
>   <AllowedSourceNonDomainComputers></AllowedSourceNonDomainComputers>
>   <AllowedSourceDomainComputers>O:NSG:NSD:(A;;GA;;;DC)(A;;GA;;;NS)</AllowedSourceDomainComputers>
> </Subscription>
> ```

6. Apply Group Policy Settings on the source computer (gpupdate /force). This causes the source computer to show up on the subscription in the Event Viewer Subscription with the green check-mark. Sometimes this works and sometimes the source computer is not even listed in the source computer list.
7. With events in the Notifications log on the source computer, and new log entries being generated there, events are failing to appear in the ForwardedEvents log on the collector computer.

---

I have ran the following commands on the collector and have found no issues:

- winrm id /r:`<Source Computer>` /a:none
- winrm id /r:`<Source Computer>` /u:`<username>` /p:`<password>`
- wecutil gr `<subscription name>`

Sometimes I see the following Warning in the Collector’s System event log:

"The WinRM service is not listening for WS-Management requests. 
 User Action 
If you did not intentionally stop the service, use the following command to see the WinRM configuration: winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener"

Can someone tell me why this isn’t working?

Thanks!